# Fullcalendar - color each event differently

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar to pull data from a Google Calendar but it does not pull in the color associated on google's side - how do I get Fullcalendar to color events based on index or count of event per day (I only use Month view)

example, I want Fullcalendar to color all events like:

per day
event #1  (default color)
event #2  red
event #3  green

for every day.

thanks.

Comment: how are you pulling the data from Google? There's more than one way.

Comment: I'm using this to pull data from Google: [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/).  However, my question is more about setting the color of events based on how many events are on a single day in the Month view, not where the data is coming from.

Comment: I know that, but the solution can potentially depend on the method used to fetch the data. You've got a bit of a problem here really because you don't know how many events there are per day until they have all finished rendering, and obviously once they've all finished rendering they are already coloured in. You can still change it after, but it will flicker for a moment. If you were fetching the events yourself via Google's Calendar API, for instance, you'd have access to the data before it went to fullCalendar, and could check this in advance and add colour information to the event objects.

Comment: Perhaps you can make your own modification to the gcal.js file which would enable you to add this feature.

Comment: I was thinking of using something like eventAfterAllRender, and iterating through the events, and every other event per day changing the color.  This would then work regardless of source.  I'm just not sure how to proceed.

Comment: you'd have to start by fetching all the events using the "clientEvents" method which fullCalendar provides, then examine the dates for each, categorise them by the day(s) they occur on, and then loop the events for each day and colour them appropriately to their position. You might have fun if an event crosses over more than one day